# AngularJS - orderBy distance function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm extremely new to AngularJS so go easy on me... :-) I am in the process of building a new PhoneGap app with Ionic Framework and AngularJS. I have a list of locations that outputs in a list view and a function that will look up the user's location and get the distance between their current location and the location in the list. These currently both work correctly and I can see my list, sort by normal fields (name, etc).

What I would like to do is to have a preferences screen where the user will be able to set their preferred sorting option. I have already setup my basic preference controller as well that currently only is storing the preference to sort by 'name' but I'd like it to sort by distance that is calculated by a function seen below. But since the distance function seems to be in this controller, I don't know how to make it sort by that? Do I need to make a filter that runs the distance function?

Again, I'm new so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my controller:

```
.controller('LocationsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, LocationsService, SettingsService)     {
  $scope.locations = {};

  $scope.navTitle = "List of Locations";

  $scope.rightButtons =  [{
    type: 'button-icon button-clear ion-more',
    tap: function(e) {
      $scope.openSortModal();
    }
  }];

  // Method called on infinite scroll
  // Receives a "done" callback to inform the infinite scroll that we are done
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      // Placeholder for later
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    }, 1000);
  }

  $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
    content: 'Getting current location...',
    showBackdrop: false
  });

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    var coords = $scope.currentLocation = [pos.coords.longitude, pos.coords.latitude];
    $scope.locations = LocationsService.allSync();
    $scope.sortLoc = SettingsService.get('sortLocBy');
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }, function(error) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Unable to get location: ' + error.message
    }).then(function(res) {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
      // not working
    });
  });

  $scope.distanceFromHere = function (_item, _startPoint) {
    var start = null;

    var radiansTo = function (start, end) {
      var d2r = Math.PI / 180.0;
      var lat1rad = start.latitude * d2r;
      var long1rad = start.longitude * d2r;
      var lat2rad = end.latitude * d2r;
      var long2rad = end.longitude * d2r;
      var deltaLat = lat1rad - lat2rad;
      var deltaLong = long1rad - long2rad;
      var sinDeltaLatDiv2 = Math.sin(deltaLat / 2);
      var sinDeltaLongDiv2 = Math.sin(deltaLong / 2);
      // Square of half the straight line chord distance between both points.
      var a = ((sinDeltaLatDiv2 * sinDeltaLatDiv2) +
              (Math.cos(lat1rad) * Math.cos(lat2rad) *
                      sinDeltaLongDiv2 * sinDeltaLongDiv2));
      a = Math.min(1.0, a);
      return 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    };

    if ($scope.currentLocation) {
      start = {
        longitude: $scope.currentLocation[0],
        latitude: $scope.currentLocation[1]
      };
    }
    start = _startPoint || start;

    var end = {
      longitude: _item.location.lng,
      latitude: _item.location.lat
    };

    var num = radiansTo(start, end) * 3958.8;
    return Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
  }
})
```

And here is my template:

```
<ion-view title="{{navTitle}}" left-buttons="leftButtons">
  <ion-content header-shrink scroll-event-interval="5">
    <ion-list class="locations-list">
      <ion-item class="location-item" ng-repeat="loc in locations | orderBy:sortLoc" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/location/{{loc.id}}/details" style="background-image:url('{{loc.photos.0.url}}');">
        <div class="location-title">
          <p>{{loc.name}}</p>
          <span class="distance-indicator"><span class="digit">{{distanceFromHere(loc)}}</span><span class="unit">mi</span></span>
        </div>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: I am looking for the same use case as well. Do you have the source code for your finial app so I can learn from you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the `orderBy` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). As the `orderBy` expression, you can use a function which generates a value to use for sorting. All you should need to do is to put the `distanceFromHere` function in your `sortLoc` scope variable (or change the filter to `orderBy:distanceFromHere`).

Comment: oh wow. I've been fighting with it all day and it was that simple. I feel like a dummy now... I was trying `orderBy` with `orderBy:distanceFromHere(loc)` originally and that wasn't working so I didn't know if I was doing everything wrong or not. Thanks!